# How can prevent innerHTML replacing single quote with double quote?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const content = document.body.innerHTML;
alert(content);
```

```html
<div id='html'>html</div>
<div id='content'>
</div>
```

Please have a look at my source html code ,all id's value wrapped with single quote :

```
id='html'
id='content'
```

The alert result is

```
<div id="html">html</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const content = document.body.innerHTML;
        alert(content);
    </script>
```

How can prevent `innerHTML` replacing single quote with double quote?Keep the output as my primitive html format.

Comment: Setting `.innerHTML` corrects and normalises your input. It doesn't give the exact source, it gives *an* HTML representation that can re-create what's there.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. But if you want, you can replace the single quotes in the string (innerHTML) with double quotes:-

```
  <div id="html">html</div>
  <div id="content"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
         var content = document.body.innerHTML;
          content = content.replace(/'/g, '"');
         alert(content);
  </script>
```